# Start chat with context

Tags: python, google-gemini, google-generativeai

```
model = GenerativeModel("gemini-1.0-pro", generation_config={"temperature": 0}, tools=[retail_tool])
context = [
    Content(role = "user", parts = [
      Part(text = "System prompt: You are an assistent who can process json and answers off that."),
      Part(text = f"json is provided here {json.dumps(data)}")
    ]),
    Content(role = "model", parts = [Part(text = "understood")])
]
chat2 = model.start_chat(history = context)
```

I am not able to provide history to start chat conversation. Getting following error:

```
ValueError: history must be a list of Content objects.
```

I am passing content object in the array but its not happy. Ideally this method should have accepted a list of dict anyways to keep it simple.  Any idea how to solve it? I guess I am not able to create the write data type. Just need a Python expert to answer this. Relevant function signature is attached below.

```
Documentation is here: https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/vertexai/generative_models/_generative_models.py#L602
```

Comment: In your situation, when you modify `chat2 = model.start_chat(history = context)` to `chat2 = model.start_chat(history = [])`, what result will you obtain? By the way, when I tested your `context` with a sample `data`, no error occurred. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: passing history=[] work and I get the answer from Gemini. Can you attach the sample call that worked for you? TIA